# Could not convert string to float Python - Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am getting this error but everything seems ok.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
import pandas as pd

#Uploading data to Python Pandas Dataframe

db_fondos = pd.read_excel('/Users/jonathanprieto/Documents/GitHub/GoogleMaps/data/- Matriz TDF Python.xlsm',
                       sheet_name="DB Fondos")
ts_flujos = pd.read_excel('/Users/jonathanprieto/Documents/GitHub/GoogleMaps/data/- Matriz TDF Python.xlsm',
                       sheet_name="TS Flujos")
ts_ind_fin = pd.read_excel('/Users/jonathanprieto/Documents/GitHub/GoogleMaps/data/- Matriz TDF Python.xlsm',
                       sheet_name="TS Ind. Fin.")
ts_market = pd.read_excel('/Users/jonathanprieto/Documents/GitHub/GoogleMaps/data/- Matriz TDF Python.xlsm',
                       sheet_name="TS Market data")
db_posiciones = pd.read_excel('/Users/jonathanprieto/Documents/GitHub/GoogleMaps/data/- Matriz TDF Python.xlsm',
                       sheet_name="DB Posiciones")
print('Carga completada')


#NaN = np.nan
#db_posiciones["Id. Pos."] = NaN
#db_posiciones.head()

print(db_posiciones)

diccionario=db_fondos.set_index("Fondo")["Id. Fondo"].to_dict()

for index, row in db_posiciones.iterrows():
    ipos = row["Fondo"]
    print(ipos)
    if ipos in diccionario:
        idpos=diccionario[ipos]
        twofirst=row["Fondo"][:2]
        twofirst = twofirst[0:2]
        print(idpos+"-"+twofirst)
        db_posiciones["Id. Pos."].values[index] = str(idpos)+"-"+str(twofirst)
        print(index)
print(db_posiciones)
```

Could anyone told me why I am getting this error:

```
File "/Users/jonathanprieto/Documents/GitHub/GoogleMaps/test.py", line 36, in <module>
db_posiciones["Id. Pos."].values[index] = str(idpos) + "-" + str(twofirst)
```

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '91_AGSACB_08-65'

Comment: Well, what kinds of values are stored in the `db_posiciones["Id. Pos."].values` column? Is `'91_AGSACB_08-65'` that kind of value? Are you surprised that ` str(idpos)+"-"+str(twofirst) ` produces that kind of value? Are you expecting the conversion to happen automatically? If so, what should the value be in this case?

Comment: In db_posiciones["Id. Pos."].values[index], the is NaN value because it an empty cell, the value 91_AGSACB_08-65 is exactly why I want to put in the cell.

Comment: Okay, what kind of thing is NaN (hint: what does the error message say couldn't be done)? What kind of thing is `91_AGSACB_08-65` (hint: what does the error message say it was)?

Comment: `db_posiciones["Id. Pos."].values[index]` is the wrong way to try to slice your data. Just do `db_posiciones["Id. Pos."].loc['91_AGSACB_08']` or `.iloc[]`. Please read the [pandas Getting Started doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html) about how to slice properly with `.loc[]` / `.iloc[]` asnd string/ integer row-labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You're getting this because your series is string, but it contains some NAs, which actually get represented in pandas as `nan`, which is a float value** (that's how [`pd.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) will handle it). That's why pandas gives a strange warning claiming the string series is a float:

#### Solution: first, fill any NA values in your string column with empty-string:

```
df[column].fillna('', inplace=True)
```

Notes:

- make sure to use `fillna(..., inplace=True)` so you don't need to assign the result back to `df['column']` to prevent it getting thrown away.
- for doc, see [`pd.Series.fillna(..., inplace=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html)
- you can fill several Series (/columns) in your dataframe at once, with `df.fillna` rather than `df[column].fillna(..., inplace=True)` on each column. See [`pd.DataFrame.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Comment: I just tried with this: db_posiciones["Id. Pos."].fillna(" ") and I have the same problem:   File "/Users/jonathanprieto/Documents/GitHub/GoogleMaps/test.py", line 36, in <module>
    db_posiciones["Id. Pos."].values[index] = str(idpos)+"-"+str(twofirst)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '91_AGSACB_08-65'

Comment: @JonathanPrieto: make sure to use `fillna(..., inplace=True)` so you don't need to assign the result back to `df['column']` to prevent it getting thrown away.

Comment: JonathanPrieto: `db_posiciones["Id. Pos."].values[index]` is the wrong way to try to slice your data. Just do `db_posiciones["Id. Pos."].loc['91_AGSACB_08']` or `.iloc[]`. Please read the [pandas Getting Started doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html) about how to slice properly.

Comment: As a general tip, you should never need to use `df[column].values` in pandas, unless you're doing something unusual like converting to matrices for numpy/scipy. So if you find yourself feeling the urge to use `.values`, go check the [`10 minutes to pandas` doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html) first, there is almost surely a standard pandas method or two on DataFrame or Series that you can use instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[column] = df[column].apply(lambda x: float(x.split()[0].replace(',', '')))
```

Comment: Could you explain me this ?

Comment: I am getting the following error:  File "/Users/jonathanprieto/Documents/GitHub/GoogleMaps/test.py", line 25, in <lambda>
    db_posiciones["Id. Pos."] = db_posiciones["Id. Pos."].apply(lambda x: float(x.split()[0].replace(',', '')))
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: You can just directly do `df[column].fillna('')` to fill NAs with [`pd.Series.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) , you don't need this.